# How to put PNG into TImageList?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

I have a PNG image that i'm trying to load into a `TImageList` at design-time:

[image]

I have an image list, which i then try to open my png:

[image]

Once added, the image that appears is not correct:

[image]

What steps in opening a file am i missing?

## Edit: Lets try some more files

[image] [image]

[image] [image]

[image] [image]

## Edit: More settings

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any other variations anyone would like to see?

Comment: Are you shure your PNG's are PNG's not just Bitmaps with the wrong extension?

Comment: Works fine here. Don't understand why you are modifying the `DrawingStyle` and `Masked` properties of the image list. Or indeed how you are able to modify the Transparent Color drop down. I cannot do that. Can you perhaps upload the actual files to a file share site. Also, why are you doing this at design time. It's not going to play well with font scaling and high DPI.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Other answers elsewhere **insisted** that you have to some specific `DrawingStyle` and `ColorDepth`. The rest is my random attempts to make things work. I'll post more screenshots of different settings of the `TImageList`

Comment: When I build 32bpp image lists I set ColorDepth and nothing else.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan That should match my second addendum screenshot.

Comment: It's a little odd that I cannot reproduce this. Can we be sure that we are using identical files? If you right click the images in the question above, and add to an image list with just the `ColorDepth` changed to `cds32bit`, does it get messed up. Works just dandy here.

Comment: `unit ImgEdit;`  with `TransparentColor.Enabled :=  Items[Index].CanChangeTransparent;` leading to
`FCanChangeTransparent := (Graphic is TBitmap and
      (TBitmap(Graphic).AlphaFormat = afIgnored)) or
      (not (Graphic is TBitmap) and not Graphic.Transparent);` So your problem should not exist with PNG's containing transparent info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was that I was using a function contained in the [GraphicEx library](http://www.delphi-gems.com/index.php/libs/graphicex-library):

```
procedure Stretch(NewWidth, NewHeight: Cardinal; Filter: TResamplingFilter; 
      Radius: Single; Source: TBitmap);
```

The call to this function is abstracted away inside a *ResizeGraphic* helper function.

The problem is that `GraphicEx` also has it's own `PNG` implementation:

```
TPNGGraphic = class(TGraphicExGraphic)
```

which is then registered at runtime as an available file format:

```
initialization
RegisterFileFormat('png', gesPortableNetworkGraphic, '',
      [ftRaster], False, True, TPNGGraphic);
```

## Enter Custom Controls

We use some custom Delphi components.

Some of these components directly or indirectly import a reference to `GraphicEx`. This then means that `GraphicEx` is taking over handling of the `PNG` file type away from whatever class exists inside the IDE at design.

The solution was to define away all the `RegisterFileFormat` lines in the `initialization` section of `GraphicEx.pas`

```
{$ifdef PortableNetworkGraphic}
RegisterFileFormat('png', gesPortableNetworkGraphic, '', [ftRaster], False, True, TPNGGraphic);
{$endif}
```

and then re-build all my runtime and design-time packages.

Once that was done, and the IDE restarted:

[image]

> **Note**: Any code released into public domain. No attribution required.